# How do I reference a jar from an eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, fitnesse

I have some code copied from the fitness website:

```
package fixtures;

import static fitnesse.util.ListUtility.list; //fitnesse.util can not be resolved
import static util.ListUtility.list;  //this one resolves but is no help in getting list to work below


import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class EmployeesHiredBefore {
  private Date date;

  public EmployeesHiredBefore(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
  }

  public void table(List<List<String>> table) {
    //optional function
  }

  public List<Object> query() {

    return
      list(
        list(
          list("employee number", "1429"),
          list("first name", "Bob"),
          list("last name", "Martin"),
          list("hire date", "10-Oct-1974")
        ),
        list(
          list("employee number", "8832"),
          list("first name", "James"),
          list("last name", "Grenning"),
          list("hire date", "15-Dec-1979")
        )
      );
  }
}
```

I have added to build path with add external jar of fitnesse.jar its contents includes `util/ListUtility.class`

Anyone know how to reference this jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of fitnesse.jar (from http://fitnesse.org/FrontPage.FitNesseDevelopment.DownLoad) has a `util.ListUtility` class but not `fitnesse.util.ListUtility`.

So you (probably) want

```
import static util.ListUtility.list;
```

but what problem are you actually getting when you use this import? In what way do things not work?

Comment: yep. That seems to have done it. I was wondering if the fitnesse came from the name of the jar or not (I am new to this language). The Other Errors that where still present on the lines that called list disappeared while I was cleaning my teeth (no causal relation ship is assumed).

Answer (score 0):

In the fitnesse jar there is no package called "fitnesse.util". 
Recheck.
I could find only
util.ListUtility.list;

Answer (score 0):

I am using fitnesse version - release 20150114.
There is no ListUtility under following:

1. Util package
2. fitnesse.util package
   I resolved it by creating ListUtility class in source by followng way.

[Fitnesse importing util.ListUtility.list; is giving error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241615/fitnesse-importing-util-listutility-list-is-giving-error)