# Fitnesse importing util.ListUtility.list; is giving error

Tags: java, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim, selenium-fitnesse-bridge

I am trying to 
`import static util.ListUtility.list;` but it is giving error:

> The import util.ListUtility cannot be resolved

I have fitnesse-standalone.jar in my path. I explored util package in jar. It seems that it is not any more. I downloaded latest version of fitnesse.Is it deprecated and not supported any more?

I also tried with `fitnesse.util.ListUtility` but no avail.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is resolved, as util.ListUtility.list; is not in fitnesse jar so I created the class in my source with same utility.

Comment: Something like this - https://code.google.com/p/jeeunit/source/browse/jeeunit-fit-parent/jeeunit-fit-unclebob/src/main/java/util/ListUtility.java?r=5e4cd07b144bf5290e29d90055b2fa15c8cf7f2b&spec=svn7bba379a7b1321598c0e85828492fb3d18b520d7